# How can I use a custom mysql column type - varbinary(16) in Rails

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, activerecord, ipv6

Is it possible for Rails 4.1.x or 4.2.x ActiveRecord to be setup to support a varbinary(16) column for a MySQL database?

I would like to store and Access IPv6 address in the varbinary(16) column.
MySQL requires using the INET6_ATON and INET6_NTOA functions to convert to/from binary.

Have googled around and haven't found anything that shows that this is possible or how to do it.

I can't use another database, so am stuck with MySQL.

Comment: This resource might helpful for you http://www.dweebd.com/ruby/mysql-varbinary-columns-in-rails-migrations/

Comment: Where would I put that config?

Comment: Not sure but you can add this into config/initializers

Answer (score 1):

Rails 4 and up will use `VARBINARY` in cases where the limit is explicitly present and less than or equal to 255 bytes.

In your migration, you can specify:

`add_column :my_table, :column_name, :binary, limit: 16`

This functionality was added to give a performance benefit over the previously used `BLOB` type. [This pull request](https://github.com/rails/rails/pull/7960) contains the details.